# Efficient caching strategy for a symmetric function in Python

Tags: python, optimization, caching

I have code of the following form (this example is much simpler but it gets the point across):

```py
i = range(10)   # in reality much larger

def func(a, b): # my actual function is much more complicated than this, but the
                # important thing is that func(a, b) = func(b, a)
    return a + b

total = 0
for i_prime in i:
    for i_prime_prime in i:
        if i_prime != i_prime_prime:
            total += func(i_prime, i_prime_prime)
```

How can I reduce the number of times I call `func`, taking advantage of the fact that `func(a, b) = func(b, a)`. I came up with the following:

```py
cache = {}
total = 0
for i_prime in i:
    for i_prime_prime in i:
        if i_prime != i_prime_prime:
            key = str(list({i_prime, i_prime_prime}))
            if key in cache.keys():
                total += cache[key]
            else:
                temp       = func(i_prime, i_prime_prime)
                cache[key] = temp
                total     += temp
```

But I feel like doing `key = str(list({i_prime, i_prime_prime}))` is not the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: What's in `i` ?

Comment: Is computing that `total` your actual use case or just a toy demo?

Comment: @KellyBundy in my real code `i` is a list of indices to a list of objects that I pass to the real `func`. And `total` is just a toy demo but is sufficiently similar to my actual use case.

Comment: Are there duplicates in that list? Are the indices meaningful or do you just use them to fetch the corresponding objects? Are you actually processing all pairs, or is that also just part of the toy demo?

Comment: @KellyBundy there are no duplicates in the list and the indices are not meaningful. And I actually need to process all pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the function "irregularly", then caching/flipping like Frank [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76478574/12671057) is good. Or if you want to roll your own, then

```
key = str(sorted((a, b)))
if key in cache:
```

or

```
key = tuple(sorted((a, b)))
if key in cache:
```

or

```
key = (a, b) if a < b else (b, a)
if key in cache:
```

would likely be better than your

```
key = str(list({a, b}))
if key in cache.keys():
```

because:

1. Sorting a pair really does make `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` equal. Unlike your set, as for example `list({0, 8})` and `list({8, 0})` become the **different** keys `[0, 8]` and `[8, 0]` (implementation detail, but has been like this for many years) while sorting leads to `[0, 8]` for both.
2. Creating a keys view for each membership check is pointless and wasteful.
3. Tuple *might* be faster than string, at least it should be at creation, although it might be slower at hashing. Would have to measure, with the actual data.

But if you do something with all pairs, each pair once, like your demo shows and like your comments suggest, then it might be better to simply only produce one of `(a, b)` and `(b, a)`, compute its function value, and incorporate it into your result twice:

```py
from itertools import combinations

total = sum(
    2 * func(a, b)
    for a, b in combinations(i, 2)
)
```

Or even:

```
from itertools import combinations, starmap

total = 2 * sum(starmap(func, combinations(i, 2)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVIxbsMwDAQ66hVXdLEbF0gzFQHyi-4F7cgJAUsyaGrIW7pkaR_V11Ry3MRJO1WDJIp3uiPB98_-oPvgj8ePqO3Ty9fdK2MDIb-zxfOyBPAA9hBLHesBLjZ7dCQ7K8ZsbYs2-qagCnW5Tkh3ADUaqRvflYMHDyeSC2LRBNd33JDaLXRPPm08JHLUdLMGNytJuz6Iks959rv8W-LpTDa5HYO6ApXjD2I1igdhgdoYDZrsbLA0bRDwWy_sbC6J1yN69vorlxe3Z9L95hq5vjJ8ElpMdiZgdc0ojUmn12IEp8i0EhxYrWgI3TDVm_tUs6fcwOFSwhBdMUqu8DjrwLmMHGX3c3bBFVal-Y9whUFJHPUXB1k4u5gSRTZR_aFX3uidhmuasZ9Z-wY)

Answer (score 1):

I'm lazy.  I'd just used Python's already existing @cache and live with the minor inefficiency:

```
@cache
def f(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return f(b, a)
    .... calculate f(a, b) ...
```

If this turned out to be utterly time critical, I'd try harder.  But three lines of code gives me almost everything I need.